# How can I verify that the function $f$ and its simplified version are same?

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions, polynomials

I have the function $f=f(x,y,z)$ and rewrite it in the `PolynomialForm` and `TraditionalOrder` ; then, I try to verify the result by computing `result= f - pol` and I expect that it to be zero but it gives me a function that cannot be simplified any more.

How can I verify that $f=pol$?

```
f = ( 4 x^2 - (-1 + x^2)^2 Cos[2 x] + (1 + x^2)^2 Cos[4 x] + (-1 + x^2)^2 Sin[x]^2 (Cos[2 z] + Cos[y]));

pol = PolynomialForm[ f // ExpandAll, TraditionalOrder -> True];

result= f - pol // FullSimplify[#, Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals &&   y \[Element] Reals && z \[Element] Reals && x > 0] &
```

Comment: `Form` wrappers are for display. Use `pol = PolynomialForm[f // ExpandAll, TraditionalOrder -> True][[1]];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f = (4 x^2 - (-1 + x^2)^2 Cos[2 x] + (1 + x^2)^2 Cos[
      4 x] + (-1 + x^2)^2 Sin[x]^2 (Cos[2 z] + Cos[y]));

pol = PolynomialForm[Collect[f, x], TraditionalOrder -> True];

Head@pol

(* PolynomialForm *)

pol[[1]] == f // Simplify

(* True *)
```

The various `Form`s display wrappers (e.g., [`PolynomialForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolynomialForm.html), [`MatrixForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixForm.html)), are for display purposes only and should not be included in the definition of variables to be used in subsequent calculations. You can use parentheses to isolate the variable definition from the display wrapper. For example,

```
(f = (4 x^2 - (-1 + x^2)^2 Cos[2 x] +
     (1 + x^2)^2 Cos[4 x] +
     (-1 + x^2)^2 Sin[x]^2 
      (Cos[2 z] + Cos[y]))) // PolynomialForm[Collect[#, x],
   TraditionalOrder -> True] &
```

[image]

Or

```
f // Collect[#, x] & // TraditionalForm
```

[image]